# Azure Function timer trigger failed runs execution of stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-functions

I want to execute stored procedure on my azure function timer trigger.
The function deployed successfully.
But, when the function runs, I get this error stack trace messages

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
...
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
...
Inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception handled at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError:
...
```

Here is the code,

```
[FunctionName("DimensionFactTableUpdate")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%CronJobSchedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger UpdateFactDimensionTable function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    var _connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DbConnectionString");
    var _storedProcedureDimension = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StoredProcedureDimension");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_storedProcedureDimension))            
        return;            

    #region UPDATE DIMENSION TABLE
    try
    {
        log.Info($"[START] Update dimension table at: {DateTime.Now}");
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(_storedProcedureDimension, connection) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            {
                var status = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
        log.Info($"[END] Update Dimension table at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.ToString());
    }            
    #endregion 
}
```

Thanks.

======

**EDITED :**

Here is the exception messages,

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Comment: Could you include the full exception ? (ToString of the exception.) Instead of parts of the stacktrace

Comment: And maybe validate `connectionstring` and `storedprecuderdimension` variables if they are not null or empty.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Here is the exception message > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you received a Timeout exception:

This can mean 2 things. You are not able to login to the SQL Server.
Does this exception occur on the `Open()` statement?
Then Investigate the login issues:

- Is your connection string correct?
- Is your database (tcp and port) accessible from azure? (this is Ok if you are using Azure SQL Databases)
- Does the login have the correct permissions?
- Check the SQL server error log `sp_readerrorlog` for more information why the login failed.

Otherwise if you receive the exception on `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` it's a timeout.

**Option 1:** The easy way, but not necessarily the best

Increase the timeout on the `SqlCommand` like

```
command.CommandTimeout = 60; // 60 seconds = 1 Minute
```

**Option 2**: The costly way

Scale out your SQL Server DB (assuming you are using Azure SQL)

**Option 3** : The most time consuming way

Investigate why your Stored Procedure is slow, and solve this.
This could have many issues, blocking, waits, poor or no indexes, cursors/whiles, ...

Comment: No issue found on the login.

Comment: Option 2 worked well. But for sure, I need  to improve my stored procedure.